# Php Contact Form Subject Field

Tags: php, forms, joomla-k2

I have this on my contact.php file:

```
'.JText::_('PLG_LABEL_NAME').'
      <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="'.$_POST['name'].'" />
      <br />
      <br />
      '.JText::_('PLG_LABEL_EMAIL').'
      <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="'.$_POST['email'].'" />
      <br />
      <br />
      '.JText::_('PLG_LABEL_SUBJECT').'
      <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="'.$_POST['subject'].'" />
      <br />
      <br />
```

Which of these two or where do i add these codes?

```
<?php if($this->item->params->get('itemTitle')): ?>
<?php echo $this->item->title; ?>
```

Thanks in advance by the way.

---

It's outside of the scope file. The file containing the item is in item.php and it has this line to get the item title and display it as

```
<?php if($this->item->params->get('itemTitle')): ?>
      <!-- Item title -->
      <h2 class="itemTitle">
        <?php echo $this->item->title; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
$html .= '<label for="contact_subject">';
$html .= '&nbsp;'. JText::_( 'Subject' ).':';
if ($this->item->params->get('itemTitle')) $html .= $this->item->title;
$html .= '</label>';
```

Comment: Oh Sorry, I post the wrong html syntax i have this on my contactform.php

if (!$_POST["subject"]) {$errori .= JText::_('PLG_ERROR_NO_SUBJECT')."<br>";}

and 

'.JText::_('PLG_LABEL_SUBJECT').'
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="'.$_POST['subject'].'" />
    <br />

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow, can you edit the question with the relevant code in proper code sections?

Comment: So where exactly in the HTML do you want `$this->item->title` to appear?

Comment: If possible, I'd like it to be on the Subject Input Field. Thanks

Comment: Yea, that's it. I'd like to populate the subject input field with the current item title.

Comment: ...and does `<input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" value="'.$this->item->title.'" />` not work...?

Comment: No, the field is still empty.

Comment: I what context does the above code appear? Is it inside an object or in the outer scope of the file? You need to get the `title` property of the object that contains it - how can you get a reference to that object?